# Can I access a annotation on the instance of a bean to be injected

Tags: spring

Given a class :

```java
public ClassA {
    @Autowired
    @SomeAnnotation("foo")
    private ClassB bar;
}

@Component
@Scope(prototype)
public ClassB {
    private String someString;
}
```

I would like to write some bean processor (post construct...) that can at `ClassB` construction time can access the `@SomeAnnotation` on the intances that `ClassB` is getting injected into so that I can set the value of `someString` to "foo".

I know this isn't very IoC and I'm going to guess it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this with a `@PostConstruct` of `ClassA`:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(){
  SomeAnnoation someAnnotation =  this.getClass().getField("bar").getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
  bar.someString(someAnnotation.value());
}
```

**Update:** - General solution using a BeanPostProcessor :

```
public class SomeAnnotationFieldInitalizer implements BeanPostProcessor{

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getFields();
        if (fields!=null){
            for (Field field:fields){
                SomeAnnotation someAnnotation = field.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
                if (someAnnotation!=null){
                    try {
                        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                        field.set(bean, someAnnotation.value());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would have to implement this method on all classes that I would like to be like `ClassA`. I was looking for a general solution such as a `BeanPostProcessor` that can be registered in the Spring Context.

Comment: Well, that is a good thought, you can actually move the same code to a bean post processor and it should still work, I have added an updated answer.